# Speed of light, breaking the barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light

when the sound barrier is broken, a series of concentric waves of sound is produced.Does it mean when the speed of light barrier is broken, a ripple of photons are created in the space-time fabric?

Answer (score 5):

The light barrier cannot be broken in vacuum as you should know by now. [c is the velocity of light in vacuum.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light)

But, within a medium light can have a lower [phase velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity) in the medium, depending on the index of refraction of the medium. There the barrier phenomenon  can appear and it is called [Cherenkov radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Cerenkov_radiation).

> While electrodynamics holds that the speed of light in a vacuum is a universal constant (c), the speed at which light propagates in a material may be significantly less than c. For example, the speed of the propagation of light in water is only 0.75c. Matter can be accelerated beyond this speed (although still to less than c) during nuclear reactions and in particle accelerators. Cherenkov radiation results when a charged particle, most commonly an electron, travels through a dielectric (electrically polarizable) medium with a speed greater than that at which light would otherwise propagate in the same medium.

This phenomenon has practical applications as in particle detectors etc.

Answer (score 3):

Speed of light in the vacuum cannot be exceeded by matter, so the barrier cannot be broken.

Speed of light in medium, however, may be surpassed by a charged particle also moving in that medium, resulting in [Cherenkov radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation). But it is hardly something as "ripple in the space-time fabric".

Answer (score 0):

For particles to go faster than the speed of light requires that Lorentz invariance must be broken. It is possible to formulate theories that violate Lorentz invariance, and such theories do indeed predict that particles going faster than the speed of light will emit radiation and lose energy as a result. This effect was invoked by Andrew Cohen and Sheldon  Glashow [in this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6562) to show that the results of the OPERA experiments that appeared to show that neutrinos had been observed travelling faster than light, could not be correct. The energy distribution of the neutrino beam at the detection point would have had to be affected by this energy loss but this was not observed.